# generic "type expected" error message in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin and I've written the following code and I'm getting a compile error.

Is there any solution?

```kotlin
class CommonResponse<T>(
    var result: Result, var data: T?, var message: String?, var errorCode: String?
) {

    companion object {

        fun <T> success(): CommonResponse<*> {
            return CommonResponse(Result.SUCCESS, null, null, null)
        }

        fun <T> success(data: T): CommonResponse<*> {
            return CommonResponse(Result.SUCCESS, data, null, null)
        }
}
```

```kotlin
val success = CommonResponse.success<>() // compile error!! "Type expected"
```

I don't know why this error occurs.

Comment: What type of `CommonResponse` do you want to create with that code?

Comment: data is null. so wild card type or any type.

Comment: Okay... Let me change the way I ask, how do you intend on using `success`? Are you intending on passing to something that expects a `CommonResponse<String>`, for example?

Comment: I'm new to Kotlin, so I don't know what you mean. I put * in the return type, and I put null in the data, so it cannot be returned as a String.

Comment: I had assumed that returning `CommonResponse<*>` wasn't intentional, since it isn't a very useful type, but from what you are saying, it seems like the `<T>` is not intentional? Remove the `<T>` then, also remove the `<>` after `success`.

Comment: @majava That's not a Kotlin issue but a generics issue.

Comment: Why *  bad  ? and what other alternatives are there? T can never be eliminated. In the above code, null is passed, but data is passed in various overloading types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `success()` is not related to any specific `T`, so you should not define `T` for `success()`:

```kotlin
val success = CommonResponse.success()

fun success(): CommonResponse<*> { ... }
```

As a side note, `CommonResponse<*>` is probably not the best type here. `<*>` means: "type of the data is unknown". Your case is more like: "there is no data at all", so it makes more sense to use `CommonResponse<Unit>` or alternatively `CommonResponse<Nothing>`. It depends on how do you like to expose the information that there is no data. In the first case `data` property should return the `Unit` object, in the second case accessing `data` should throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what it is you are trying to accomplish here, but if you want it to pass compile check, you can just simply change the generic type you want to Any.

```kotlin
  CommonResponse.success<Any>()
```

will do just fine.